# Getting FileNotFoundError in a Python project although file is there

Tags: python-3.6

I have made some changes in following folders structure for a Python project-

[image: folder structure]

Inside the categories folder my csv file is there and I am reading it from a file reside inside merchants folder.

I am facing FileNotFoundError: File b'/categories/abc.csv' does not exist in folllowing line-

```
rfile = pd.read_csv('categories/abc.csv')
```

And I am generating this csv file from a python file reside inside the utils folder.

Now if I re run my csv file generation file from utils folder I am getting-
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'categories/abc.csv'

Can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rfile = pd.read_csv('../categories/abc.csv')
```

First of all come out of your merchants directory and navigate to categories directory, as mentioned in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The path you are passing is relative to python file. So make sure either pass absolute path to CSV file, or relative path is correct.

Comment: If I give the complete path then it will path of my local system; how can I manage this for production?

Comment: Then relative path is the way to go, I think your relative path is wrong. Can you tell in which folder the python file is there and which folder CSV?

Comment: Actual issue is that it is not able to find the path. I run a script from utils folder which generates a csv file inside the categories folder.But now it is not able to find the categories folder and throwing -FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'categories/abc.csv'

Comment: print the current working directory from script, before it throws error. That might give you hint.